# Geolocation Simulation Debug Dropdown in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, geolocation, simulator

There is supposedly a dropdown that lets you simulate several different geolocational coordinates in Xcode4 at runtime, feeding straight to the simulator... Where is this menu / how do you access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find this menu under **Debug** in the iOS Simulator.

[image]

Comment: I'm using v4.3 of the simulator, but somehow I do not have a Debug menu... Is there some special key combination needed to access it?

Comment: Are you using the latest of the 4.3 SDK? The iOS Simulator version should be 5.0 (266), which can be downloaded form the Mac App Store for free.

Comment: ah i had thought it was available in the stable release, but it's only in the beta?

Comment: no, the release version from the Mac App Store. The MAS does not provide betas.

Comment: WrightsCS I also cannot find Debug section in iOS Simulator menu. What  should i do to make it visible?