# How can I enable "Debug" section in iOS simulator menu?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774814/geolocation-simulation-debug-dropdown-in-xcode-4) people say that it is possible to set mock location in iOS simulator Debug menu. However I cannot find this section in iOS Simulator menu. Im using last XCode 4 from AppStore (Lion). What should I do to make it visible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it has been added since ios sdk 5.0. I have both versions(4.3.2 and 5.0BETA and corresponding xcode versions) installed separately and the menu you mean is only in 5.0 version.

Comment: Bad news =\ I hoped that it will work with last released XCode. In this answer somebody told that it is included to 4.3.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774814/geolocation-simulation-debug-dropdown-in-xcode-4